# Cakephp class not found

Tags: cakephp

Hi i am using cakephp 2 . i am including external php folder in app/webroot
and in my controller used following to include the file .

> ```
> include_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'webroot'.DS . 'socio'.DS . 'index.php');
> ```

The file is getting included but i am getting error Cannot redeclare class App .
i know i have declared App class twice . Since it is external folder having many dependencies i cant change class name . Please help me to find solution

Answer (score -1):

Can you use something like this, WWW_ROOT is a Core Definition Constant and gives full path to the webroot.

```
include_once(WWW_ROOT . 'socio'.DS . 'index.php');
```

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Comment: How is using a different constant to include the exact same file going to do anything to fix the OP's namespace issue?